# Filtrado multiple en consulta M:N

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

Tengo las tabla carro , caracteristica y carro_caracteristica ya que carro y caracteristica tiene una relacion mucho a mucho. Necesito filtrar los campos que cumplan las cararacteristicas que el usuario seleccione. Por tanto recibo en el request un arreglo con los ids de las caracteristicas que el usuario selecciono. No logro filtrar correctamente cuando es mas de una caracteristica seleccionada. He probado con where, orWhere , whereIn pero persiste el problema.

```
Car::join('car_characteristic', function($query) use($request){
            $query->on('cars.id', '=', 'car_characteristic.car_id');
                foreach($request->input('accessories') as $accessory)
                 $query->where('car_characteristic.characteristic_id', $accessory);                   
        });
```

La consulta es mas grande por que filtra por mas campos como categoria , precio, etc pero solo les publico esta parte que es la que realmente tiene problemas.
Espero me puedan ayudar. gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creería que es porque estás agregando clauslas no encadenadas. Intenta reasignando cada clausula del foreach a la variable $query `$query = $query->where('car_characteristic.characteristic_id...`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ , me devuelve exactamente lo mismo. persiste el problema.